# How can I return pointer to the first regex occurrence in a string in C?

Tags: c, regex, string, grep, strstr

At the moment, I am coding my own grep implementation and I have a problem with -o flag when it is used with regular expressions.
The following code works properly for ordinary strings:

```
void do_o(char *pattern, char *line, flags options) {
  char *copy;
  char *temp;
  long unsigned int i;
  copy = line;
  if (options.v) {
    do_o_v(pattern, line, options);
  } 
  else {
      if (options.i) {
      while (copy && strcasestr(copy, pattern))
      {
        i = 0;
        temp = strcasestr(copy, pattern);
        while (i < strlen(pattern))
        {
          printf("%c", temp[i]);
          i++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        copy = strcasestr(copy, pattern) + strlen(pattern);
      }
    } else {
      while (copy && strstr(copy, pattern))
      {
        
        i = 0;
        temp = strstr(copy, pattern);
        while (i < strlen(pattern))
        {
          printf("%c", temp[i]);
          i++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        copy = strstr(copy, pattern) + strlen(pattern);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I also need to do the same logic for with RegEx. So, everything I need is some function as strstr() or strcasestr() that will also support regex.

When I search regex examples and search my question on Google, I mainly come across examples with the functions `regexec()` and `regcomp()`. However the both return integer, not a pointer as I need. Any ideas how can i get a pointer of the first occurrence in the string?

P.S. I need pure C code

Comment: `copy` isn’t a copy, it is a reference. Also, `grep` does _everything_ by regular expression matching. You shouldn’t have a non-regex version of code. Creating a regular expression state machine is _not_ a beginner task. Are you planning to use a library, like PCRE?

Comment: I don't mind ```copy`` ` being a reference. My grep works with regular expressions with all flags expect -o. The reason is that for all flags i just needed to find at least 1 match and print the line. However, with flag -o, I need to print exactly the matched part, and the code above is what came to my mind for ordinary string, but I don't know what to do with regex.

Comment: I am doing project at School 21 which is the russian version of french school Escole 42. You might have heard about it. I don't know whether it is a beginner task, but it is the first project at school)

Comment: I am allowed to use PCRE library. Is there such a function that can satisfy my these requirements?

Comment: Most regex engines return indices into the searched string. It is just a matter of reading the docs. I am still unsure what exactly your requirements are (that is, what your assignment requires of you). Surely your prior instruction and readings have had some information about what tools you should be expected to employ to search texts? Any solution I suggest is just a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any ideas how can i get a pointer of the first occurrence in the string?

`regexec()` has argument `regmatch_t *pmatch`, which is a pointer to a data structure containing the start and end index of a match. Using the index, you can find a pointer to the first occurrence.

Here is some example code, where `get_first_match()` returns a pointer to the first match in a string (**warning**: this does not implement any sort of error handling).

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex.h>

char *get_first_match(regex_t *pattern, char *str)
{
    char *ptr = NULL;
    regmatch_t match;
    if (regexec(pattern, str, 1, &match, 0) != REG_NOMATCH) {
        ptr = &str[match.rm_so];
    }

    return ptr;
}

int main()
{
    char *string = "Example1, Example2, Example3.";
    regex_t *pattern;

    regcomp(pattern, "Example2", 0);

    printf("%s\n", get_first_match(pattern, string));

    regfree(pattern);
}
```

This will print "Example2, Example3." Take a look at the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/regexec.3.html) for more information.